# How can I search 3 different tables and output the results in one query?

Tags: php, sql, search

I'm working on a site, and have 3 tables (articles, news, and blogs) that I would like to search in one query. Each table has at least 2 columns I would like to search. (title and post)

The script below works for a query on a single table but I want to know if there is a way to modify it to work on all three tables at once...

```
    <?php 

    if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
    $keyword =  trim($_GET['keyword']) ;
    $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $keyword);



    $query = "select title,article_post from articles where title like '%$keyword%' or article_post  like '%$keyword%'";

//echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    if($result){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($db)!=0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     echo '<p> <h1 class="tite"><a href="#">'.$row['title'].'</a> </h1><br>                             '.$row['article_post'].'</p><br>'   ;
    }
    }else {
        echo 'Could not find"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
    }

    }
    }else {
    echo "";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you have a similar number of columns in each table, or can return and search a certain amount of them, then `UNION ALL` allows to append multiple selects.

Answer (score 1):

Try query using Union like :

```
select title,post from 
(
    select title,article_post as post from articles
    union all
    select title,news_post as post from news
    union all
    select title,blogs_post as post from blogs
) where title like '%$keyword%' or post  like '%$keyword%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`

```
(select title, article_post as post from articles where title like '%$keyword%' or article_post  like '%$keyword%')
UNION
(select title, news_post as post from news where title like '%$keyword%' or news_post  like '%$keyword%')
UNION
(select title, blog_post as post from articles where title like '%$keyword%' or blog_post  like '%$keyword%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) like that:

```
$query = "select title,article_post 
              from articles 
              where title like '%$keyword%' or article_post  like '%$keyword%'
          UNION ALL
          Select title, news_post 
              from post 
              where title like '%$newskeyword%' or news_post like '%$otherkeyword%'
          UNION ALL
          Select ...
          ...";
```